# Why aren't "raise" and "del" functions in Python?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, structure

One of the basic changes from Python 2 to Python 3 was making `print` a function - which, to me, makes perfect sense given its structure.  Why aren't the `raise` and `del` statements also functions?  Especially in the case of `raise` it seems like it is taking an argument and doing something with it, just like a function does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`raise` and `del` are definitely distinct from functions, each for different reasons:

- `raise` exits the current flow of execution; the normal flow of byte-code interpretation is interrupted and the stack is unwound until the next exception handler is found. Functions can't do this, they create a new stack frame instead.
- `del` can't be a function, because you must specify a specific *target*; you can't use just any expression, and what is deleted depends on the syntax given; if you use subscription, then deletion takes place for a given element in a container, or a name is removed from the current namespace. The right namespace to delete to is also dependent on the scope of the name deleted. See the [`del` statement grammar definition](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement):

  > ```
  > del_stmt ::=  "del" target_list
  > ```

  A function can't remove items from a parent namespace, nor can they distinguish between the result of a subscription expression or a direct reference. You pass *objects* to the function, but to a `del` statement you pass a name and a context (perhaps by the interpreter when deleting a local or global name).

`print` on the other hand, requires no special relationship with the current namespace or stack frame, and needs no special syntax constraints to do it's work.  It is purely functionality at the *application level*. The global `sys.stdout` reference can be accessed by functions just as much as by the interpreter. As such it didn't need to be a statement, and by moving it to a function, additional benefits were made available, such as being able to override it's behaviour and to innovate on it quicker across Python releases.

Do note that **part** of the `raise` statement was moved to application-level code instead; in Python 2 you can attach a traceback to the raised exception with:

```
raise ExceptionClass, exception_value, traceback_object
```

In Python 3, attaching a traceback to an exception has been moved to the exception itself:

```
raise Exception("foo occurred").with_traceback(tracebackobj)
```

Answer (score 2):

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/ has a list of rationals why `print` is made function. Of the five reasons, (IMO) the most relevant one is:

> print is the only application-level functionality that has a statement dedicated to it.

As explained by Alex Martelli here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1054062:

> Python statements are things the Python compiler must be specifically aware of -- they may alter the binding of names, may alter control flow, and/or may need to be entirely removed from the generated bytecode in certain conditions (the latter applies to assert). print was the only exception to this assertion in Python 2; by removing it from the roster of statements, Python 3 removes an exception, makes the general assertion "just hold", and therefore is a more regular language.

`del` and `raise` obviously alter the binding of names/alter the control flow, thus they both are okay.